# Why does `if (var = null)` compile in dart?

Tags: dart

I've recently came across this question [How do I solve the 'Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null' exception in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51052399/how-do-i-solve-the-failed-assertion-boolean-expression-must-not-be-null-excep)

where the problem comes from a *should be* invalid code that gets treated as valid.

This code can be summarized as :

```
int stuff;
if (stuff = null) { // = instead of ==
}
```

But why does this code compiles ? As the following will not.

```
int stuff;
if (stuff = 42) {
}
```

With the following compile error :

> Conditions must have a static type of 'bool'.

So I'd expect out of consistency that `if (stuff = null)` to gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>When you say `var stuff;` with no initial value it is giving `stuff` a static type of `dynamic`. Since `dyamic` *might* be a `bool`, it's legal to assign `null` to a variable of type `dynamic`, and it's legal to use a possibly null bool in a conditional, the compiler doesn't flag this. When you say `int stuff;` the compiler knows that `stuff` could not be a `bool`. The reported error in that case is cause by the static type of `stuff`, not the assignment to `null`.</s>

Edit: Got the real answer from someone who knows how to read the spec.

The static type of an assignment expression is the right hand side of the assignment. So the expression `stuff = null` has the static type of `Null` which is assignable to `bool`.

The reasoning is that the *value* of an assignment is the right hand side, so it makes sense to also use it's type. This allows expressions like:

```
int foo;
num bar;
foo = bar = 1;
```

Comment: `var` changes nothing here. I could have used `int` or `Map` or whatever. I edited my code snippet to make it clearer

Comment: Here's an example of the issue in dartpad: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/f1b096609d831bd03d88fe4f1b7ce19b

Comment: You're totally right, I had the wrong understanding of the cause. I also filed https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/1047 to see if we can add a lint for this.

Answer (score 6):

`null` is a valid value for a `bool` variable in Dart, at least until Dart supports non-nullable types.

```
bool foo = null;
```

or just

```
bool foo;
```

is valid.

Therefore in the first case there is nothing wrong from a statical analysis point of view.

In the 2nd case the type `int` is inferred because of the assignment, which is known to not be a valid boolean value.

```
bool foo = 42;
```

is invalid.

Comment: but `stuff` isn't a `bool`. And `if (stuff)`doesn't work. So I see no reason `if (stuff = null)` should work too. I can understand technically _why_. But it feels more like a bug than a feature.

Comment: same goes for `bool myVar = stuff = null`. If `stuff` isn't a bool, that shouldn't be possible.

Comment: Yeah, these are more interesting questions. I guess we better wait for @lrhn to get a proper answer ;-)

Comment: For the record, the current answer is proper. The value and type of `stuff = null` is `null` at type `Null`. You are not assigning `stuff` to anything. You are assigning `null` to two different things, and whether you write `foo = bar = null` or `bar = foo = null` only changes the order of assignment, not what value is assigned (it's `null` in both cases).

Answer (score 0):

Commonly assignment operation returns the value that it assigns.

```
int a = 0;
  print(a = 3);//Prints 3
```

So,

When stuff = null,

'stuff = null' returns null. if statement needs a boolean .null is a sub-Type of boolean.

```
if(null){}
```

is valid

When stuff = 42,

'stuff = 42' returns 42. if statement needs a boolean .42 is not a sub-Type of boolean.

```
if(42){}
```

is not valid